# Show watermark at the beginning of the video

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

Need to add watermark for first 3 seconds the video using ffmpeg. Here's what I got right now:

```
ffmpeg -y -i '255871.mov' -qscale:v 0 -qscale:a 0 -vf '[in] transpose=1 [out];movie=watermark.png , select=lte(t\,3) [bg]; [out][bg] overlay=x=20:y=main_h-60 [out]' output.mp4
```

It rotates video to the right and adds watermark at the bottom of the video for first 3 seconds. The problem is watermark is visible during the whole video.

Thought that select doesn't work at all. Tried following command

```
ffmpeg -y -i '255871.mov' -qscale:v 0 -qscale:a 0 -vf '[in] transpose=1 [out];movie=watermark.png , select=0 [bg]; [out][bg] overlay=x=20:y=main_h-60 [out]' output.mp4
```

Watermark is not visible. This is correct and proves that `select` filter works as expected. As I understand this is how ffmpeg works: it leaves last frame of the shortest video visible.

How can I force ffmpeg to discard show watermark after N seconds?

Comment: Related discussion: [FFmpeg-user: show watermark at the beginning of the video](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-March/014116.html).

Comment: I just added it for others in case the replies to that thread will be useful for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to answer it myself. [ffmpeg mailing list](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-March/014123.html) helped me to solve the issue. 
The main idea is to convert existing watermark into video using Apple Animation codec (it supports transparency) and fade out last frame of created video using [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i watermark.png -t 3 -c qtrle -vf 'fade=out:73:1:alpha=1' watermark.mov
ffmpeg -y -i '255871.mov' -qscale:v 0 -qscale:a 0 -vf '[in] transpose=1 [out];movie=watermark.mov [bg]; [out][bg] overlay=x=20:y=main_h-60 [out]' output.mp4
```

Fade out is required because ffmpeg uses last frame of overlaid video for the rest of the video. This filter makes last frame fully transparent via `alpha=1` parameter. In fact it should be `fade=out:74:1:alpha=1`, but it didn't work for me, don't know why